# What is fps, tbr, tbn, tbc in `ffmpeg`?

Tags: ffmpeg

What do the following acronyms mean in `ffmpeg` and `ffprobe`?

```
>ffprobe -hide_banner logo.gif
Input #0, gif, from 'logo.gif':
  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: gif, bgra, 320x314, 33.33 fps, 33.33 tbr, 100 tbn, 100 tbc
```

I'd imagine fps is frames per second, but I have no idea what the others are. The documentation was no help. `tbr` not found. https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html

I found `tbr` in https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html, but it was meaningless

```
‘TBR’
top back right
```

The FAQ was unhelpful too. https://www.ffmpeg.org/faq.html

As was a web search https://duckduckgo.com/?q=ffmpeg+fps%2C+tbr%2C+tbn%2C+tbc&ia=web

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/3199489 and  https://stackoverflow.com/q/43333542

Answer (score 8):

| abbrev | full | variable | explanation |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| fps | frames per second | AVStream.avg_frame_rate | average frame rate = total frames / total seconds. A variable frame rate video may have an fps of 57.16 |
| tbr | time base, real (?) | AVStream.r_frame_rate | user-friendly, target frame rate. The same variable frame rate video above could have a tbr of 60. |
| tbn | time base number (?) | AVStream.time_base | timescale (ticks per second). This number could be 90000, 15360, etc. It is used to [calculate the actual time from a PTS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43333542/what-is-video-timescale-timebase-or-timestamp-in-ffmpeg/43337235#43337235) (Presentation Time Stamp). If timescale is 90000, and PTS for a frame is 45000, that frame is displayed at 0.5 seconds. (Note: this abbreviation and variable name is a misnomer because it is actually timescale, not timebase. Timebase should be the reciprocal, such as 1/90000, 1/15360, etc.) |
| tbc | time base, codec (?) | AVCodecContext.time_base | codec timescale. Same as tbn, but for the codec. This has been deprecated and removed. |

There is no mention in the source code explaining the full words for tbr, tbn, tbc. My guess is that tbr, tbn, tbc originally meant something, but the original names no longer apply, and now would be misnomers. For example, `tbn` is not even a timebase, it's a timescale (the reciprocal). I made a guess at the original full words based on clues from the source code.

---

**References**

- variable names: https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/commit/bb3388fd60e55db0b162dc78409ae495cbc6b64f
- fps (AVStream.avg_frame_rate):

  https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/libavformat/avformat.h

  ```
  /**
   * Average framerate
   */
  AVRational avg_frame_rate;
  ```
- tbr (AVStream.r_frame_rate):

  https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/libavformat/avformat.h

  ```
  /**
   * Real base framerate of the stream.
   * This is the lowest framerate with which all timestamps can be
   * represented accurately (it is the least common multiple of all
   * framerates in the stream). Note, this value is just a guess!
   * For example, if the time base is 1/90000 and all frames have either
   * approximately 3600 or 1800 timer ticks, then r_frame_rate will be 50/1.
   */
  AVRational r_frame_rate;
  ```
- tbn (AVStream.time_base):

  https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/libavformat/avformat.h

  ```
  /**
   * This is the fundamental unit of time (in seconds) in terms
   * of which frame timestamps are represented.
   */
  AVRational time_base;
  ```
- tbc (AVCodecContext.time_base) has been deprecated/removed:

  https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/libavcodec/avcodec.h

  ```
  /**
   * This is the fundamental unit of time (in seconds) in terms
   * of which frame timestamps are represented. For fixed-fps content,
   * timebase should be 1/framerate and timestamp increments should be
   * identically 1.
   * This often, but not always is the inverse of the frame rate or field rate
   * for video. 1/time_base is not the average frame rate if the frame rate is not
   * constant.
   */
  AVRational time_base;
  ```
- deprecation commits for tbc:

  - https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/commit/202e06870eb4bbc4636aff5f461c1a0654ec2435
  - https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/commit/3749eede66c3774799766b1f246afae8a6ffc9bb#diff-a48d0f241f423be450908b536b6adec39606ef72847aeeb500cee81e88a19697
  - https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/commit/4796ec5d4ea00a86f9f6732653469e682e5266da
  - https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/commit/2b41463b8706638b9aaf967655f95ddc195c32eb

Answer (score 2):

For mp4/mov files 'tbn' is the time scale value which is signaled in mdhd-box. Each elementary stream has its own track in mp4 container and hence its own mdhd-box and its own time scale. 
'tbn' is not related to the frame rate or to the frame duration. It's simply the time scale.

For transport streams (the extension 'ts' or 'm2ts') 'tbn' is always 90kHz, this is the time scale of ISO/IEC 13818-1. Unlike to mp4 container, ts-container has fixed time-scale (90kHZ for PTS/DTS and 27MHz for PCR).